# @version annotation not working properly in jpa/eclipselink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have a base entity class

where one of the fields(Timestamp) has @**version** attribute, so Jpa will automatically increment the value.

But, sometimes the timestamp value is not getting updated, the edited date is less than the created date, but this should never happen theoretically.

I am not setting the **edited** value programmatically.

Here is my entity class:

```
public class BaseEntity implements  Serializable {  

@Column(name = "CREATED")
private Timestamp created;

@Column(name = "EDITED")
@Version
private Timestamp edited;

// other fields, getters and setters

}
```

Have read many articles about this @version annotation, but I don't understand why this value will not update, what are the reasons behind this.

If some one help me, would be great

Thanks

Comment: Check that the value has changed in the managed entity after the transaction commits (or flush has been called).  Common mistake is to look at the value in a detached entity or before the transaction has synchronized to the database, as JPA only updates the value when it is about to go to the DB.  Otherwise, give more info on the situations that you see the issue vs don't see it.

Comment: Thanks @Chris. I was actually changing property of one of the associated child entity but not the property of the parent entity in which I have `@Version Timestamp version;` property and because of that version property was not being updated with new timestamp. As soon as I changed property in parent entity, version property got the new timestamp. It works. Note that, never manually update value of a property marked with `@version`. JPA will update it with new value whenever there change in entity's property.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some basic guidelines:

- Check if you imported the right package `javax.persistence.Version`.
- Use `obj = entityManager.merge(obj);` when saving changes to already persisted entities.
- Never change the value of your version-field manually. The entity-manager will take care of it.

For further debugging edit your `persitence.xml` and add following lines to properties:

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
<property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
<property name="eclipselink.logging.sql.level" value="FINE"/>
```

This will enable fine logging and generate a lot of output. You'll be able to see the update queries and what exactly happens.

Comment: Hi  @XiCoN JFS,  
thanks for the answer, it's working fine when I checked for nearly 20 to 50 records, but some cases it's failing.

When I observe the log statements there is correct parameters to update the timestamp value.

Ya, I am using the updated the entity only.

Comment: I personally never encountered such a problem. How about you edit your `merge` function to evaluate the return-value. If it's not the expected value, make a `System.out.println(obj)` of the object. This way you might get a closer view of WHEN it actually happens. Also you might consider to look up any usages of the `edited`field in your project (getters and actual field), to see if really nothing manipulates the value of this field.